# Receiving a list of the types for the same column but with different values

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

Table t:

type (col1) || value (col2)

5 (Col1)   with value of 73 (Col2),

6 (Col1)  with value of 80 (Col2),

7 (Col1)  with value of 65  (Col2),

I would like the list of all the types from col 1 for which value (col 2) is equal to 73 and 80.

I have tried doing:

```
  SELECT `type` FROM t
  WHERE `value` = 73 
  AND `value` = 80
```

I just get back a list [] after the db.execute() call.
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like the list of all the types from col 1 for which value (col 2) is equal to 73 and 80.

Your condition checks of a record has *both* values 73 and 80, which cannot possibly succeed.

You want `OR` instead:

```
SELECT `type` FROM t WHERE `value` = 73 OR `value` = 80
```

You can shorten this with `IN`

```
SELECT `type` FROM t WHERE `value` IN (73, 80)
```

Comment: thank you! @GMB, for discussion sake, the first query you have would only return either one of those values and not a combination of `type` which has both value of  73 and 80 ?

Comment: @FishingCode: this gives you all records where value is either 73 or 80. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2):

If you want `type`s with both `value`s, then you want to compare values on *different* rows.  Aggregation can do that:

```
SELECT `type`
FROM t
WHERE `value` IN (73, 80)
GROUP BY type
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 2;
```

You only need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` if your data can have duplicates.  If this is not possible, use `COUNT(*) = 2` instead.

Comment: @FishingCode . . . This does something quite different from GMB's answer.  You either want types with BOTH values or you want types with EITHER.  If you want BOTH, then this answer works; if you want EITHER than GMB's answer works.

Comment: both look good to me, covers two cases in case I need to get the 'both' value, may come in handy dandy